# what do I need to do that all 4 of my buttons open a different new page

Tags: reactjs, button, native, listitem

Im pretty new to react so sorry if the question is bad described
i have 4 buttons and I want for each a different page that opens onPress
I can bind one open new page function to all four buttons but I can't bind one function to one button only to the button "group"

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import TrainingListItem from '../components/TrainingListItem'

export default class TrainingScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}} data={[
            
              { "_id": 1, name: "Disziplin"},
              { "_id": 2, name: "Selbstbewusstsein"},
              { "_id": 3, name: "Selbstwertgefühl"},
              { "_id": 4, name: "Vertrauen"},
              
          ]}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name} 
          renderItem={
            ({item}) => (
             <TrainingListItem training={item.name} onPress={(id) => {}}/>
            ) 
          }
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.listSeparator}/>}/>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      padding: 30,
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    listView: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    listSeparator: {
      padding: 30
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i didn´t understood that much but i will try. 
You want to open a Different page with each button ?
If so, use your name property to do so, just call your page the same name it has in the button
So you can do this in renderItem

```
renderItem={
            ({item}) => (
             <TrainingListItem training={item.name} onPress={(id) => {this.gotopage(item.name)}}/>
            ) 
          }
```

and handle that function like so

```
gotopage(NameOfPage){
//Navigate to page with name NameOfPage
//with react-navigation it will be :
 this.props.navigation.navigate(NameOfPage)
}
```

Is that what you want to do?